# The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow

After installing TensorFlow and its dependencies on a g2.2xlarge EC2 instance I tried to run an MNIST example from the getting started page:

```
python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

But I get the following warning:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:611] Ignoring gpu device 
(device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0) with Cuda compute 
capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
```

Is this a hard requirement? Any chance I could comment that check out in a fork of TensorFlow? It would be super nice to be able to train models in AWS.

Comment: We've only tested TensorFlow with compute capability >= 3.5. Several people have requested support for 3.0, and it's on our radar: see the discussion on the GitHub issue here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently only GPUs with compute capability >= 3.5 are officially supported. However, GitHub user @infojunkie has offered [a patch](https://gist.github.com/infojunkie/cb6d1a4e8bf674c6e38e) that makes it possible to use TensorFlow with a GPU with compute capability 3.0.

The official fix is in development. Meanwhile, check out the discussion on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25) for adding this support.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

There is a section in the [official installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html#install_cuda) that guides you to enable Cuda 3, but you need to build Tensorflow from source.

```
$ TF_UNOFFICIAL_SETTING=1 ./configure

# Same as the official settings above

WARNING: You are configuring unofficial settings in TensorFlow. Because some
external libraries are not backward compatible, these settings are largely
untested and unsupported.

Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to
build with. You can find the compute capability of your device at:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases
your build time and binary size. [Default is: "3.5,5.2"]: 3.0

Setting up Cuda include
Setting up Cuda lib64
Setting up Cuda bin
Setting up Cuda nvvm
Configuration finished
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple trick. You don't even have to build TF from sources.

In the file `tensorflow\python\_pywrap_tensorflow.pyd` there are two occurences of regex `3\.5.*5\.2`. Just replace both `3.5` with `3.0`.

Tested on Windows 10, Anaconda 4.2.13, Python 3.5.2, TensorFlow 0.12, CUDA 8, NVidia GTX 660m (CUDA cap. 3.0).

Comment: where is that file located? I only see a _pywrap_tensorflow_internal file

Comment: @theninjagreg According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44520245/4501221 you can follow the procedure for the _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd file. My solution was for TF 0.12 (really ancient now) and the file was probably renamed in next releases, however the trick should still work.