# tensorflow does not use gpu, but cuda does

Tags: tensorflow, optimus

tensorflow can not see my GPU. I am using a optimus setup.

nvidia-smi shows my card

```
[user@system bal]$ optirun nvidia-smi 
Mon Mar  6 13:24:05 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 378.13                 Driver Version: 378.13                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K1100M       Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      7MiB /  1999MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1847    G   /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg                        7MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

cuda sees the gpu. here is the deviceQuery output

```
[user@system release]$ optirun ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro K1100M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 1999 MBytes (2096300032 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            706 MHz (0.71 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1400 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 262144 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = Quadro K1100M
Result = PASS
```

but tensorflow does not use the gpu

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Creates a graph.
#with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2],     name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

the output seems to indicate, that only CPU is used

```
[user@system bal]$ optirun python ex.py
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 -> device: XLA_GPU device
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 -> device: XLA_CPU device
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

so, what can i do, that tensorflow sees my gpu? I am using archlinux, i assume that i have from everything the newest version. are there things, that i could check?

Comment: it is always the same.
    [user@system bal]$ TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 python ex.py
    ...
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:948] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Quadro K1100M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.

great.

Comment: You can build tf yourself to use 3.0.

Comment: I am currently trying that, but tensorflw build takes like 45 minutes on my system. I hope I gave it the correct build parameters

Comment: How many streaming multiprocessors does that card have? There's a limit in TensorFlow which excludes GPUs with too few streaming multiprocessors since those GPUs would run slower than CPU. There's an environment variable to configure this behavior, you can try setting `TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT` to a low value to make sure your GPU is included

Comment: this post is suggesting to "disable the integrated Intel Graphics in the BIOS" https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/977952/quadro-k1100m-cuda-support/

Answer (score 1):

Official miniamal CUDA Compute Capability is 3.5. Your card has 3.0. It is said that some guys can compile tensorflow to use 3.0 CC but it requires patching TF with unofficial patches. See more: [The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651810/the-minimum-required-cuda-capability-is-3-5#33686846).