# Tensorflow & Cuda capability 3.0

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, python-3.8

I am trying to use Tensorflow on a NVIDIA GRID K1. The last version of supported Cuda is 10.x.x. So, I installed Cuda 10.1 and according to here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?hl=fr I installed tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0 and Python 3.8.10.

By running this : `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` in Python I get this :
`tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1812] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GR ID K1, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.`

I've found some fix on Google as [The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651810/the-minimum-required-cuda-capability-is-3-5)  but I'm using tensorflow-gpu and I do not find any file "configure" and where to put this : TF_UNOFFICIAL_SETTING=1.

On other forum, I have found that in 2015 a patch was develop but nothing since this time about this patch.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

> By running this : tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') in Python I
> get this : tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1812]
> Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GR ID K1, pci bus id:
> 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability
> 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.

The error you're seeing indicates that TensorFlow is unable to run on your GPU (NVIDIA GRID K1) because the GPU's compute capability is lower than the minimum requirement. TensorFlow requires a GPU with a compute capability of 3.5 or higher, and unfortunately, your GPU has a compute capability of 3.0, which is not supported by TensorFlow. This limitation is due to the CUDA version used by TensorFlow.

Here are a few suggestions to address this issue

**Check GPU Compatibility:**
Confirm that your GPU (NVIDIA GRID K1) has a compute capability of 3.5 or higher. If not, you might need to use a different GPU with a higher compute capability.

**Upgrade TensorFlow:**
Try upgrading to a newer version of TensorFlow.

> pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

If you continue facing hardware limitations, you may have to consider using a previous version of TensorFlow that is compatible with the compute capability of your GPU. You can install a particular version of TensorFlow using the following command:

> pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0

**Check NVIDIA Driver Version:**
Ensure that you have the latest NVIDIA drivers installed for your GPU. Sometimes, driver updates can improve compatibility.
Consult [NVIDIA Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/#all-documents)